# What should I write in place of ACFacebookAppIdKey?

Tags: iphone

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *facebookAcc = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
    NSDictionary *options = @{ (NSString *)ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"##########",
                               (NSString *)ACFacebookPermissionsKey: [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"email"],
                               (NSString *)ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceEveryone,
                             };
    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAcc options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error){
        if (granted) {
            ACAccount *facebookAccount = [[accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookAcc] firstObject];
            NSLog(@"facebook usre name: %@, Full name: %@", facebookAccount.username, facebookAccount);

        }
        else if (error)
            NSLog(@"Error occured:%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];
}
```

and I am getting 
Error occurred:The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: invalid app id
what should I write ACFacebookAppIdKey

Comment: Please make you question in good format

Answer (score 1):

go to https://developers.facebook.com/. Create new a new app for iOS or choose your app. At the Dashboard menu, you can see your App ID. This App ID you should put to the ACFacebookAppIdKey.